# Why does git ignore all files in a directory except one?

Tags: git

I know there are many questions on how to ignore directories, and I usually haven't had any problem until now, but now I'm stuck with something I don't understand.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/src
/war
  com.example.MyProject/
  WEB-INF/
    classes/
    deploy/
    lib/
```

I want to ignore content of directories `classes/`, `deploy/` and `com.example.MyProject/`, and here is my .gitignore file:

```
*.log
war/WEB-INF/classes/
war/WEB-INF/deploy/
com.example.MyProject/
```

Files under `com.example.MyProject/` are automatically generated, and git ignores all of them except for a file named `com.example.MyProject.nocache.js`. In fact, when I do `git status` I get:

```
# On branch myBranch
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#       modified:   .gitignore
#       ......
#       modified:   war/com.example.MyProject/com.example.MyProject.nocache.js
```

Why does git refuse to ignore that single file in that directory? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a file is already being tracked by Git, adding the file to `.gitignore` won't stop Git from tracking it. You’ll need to do `git rm --cached <file>` to keep the file in your tree and then ignore it

Comment: dumb me! that had been accidentally add in a previous commit: I just had to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: And for egit users project > team > untrack, this will remove all the files in that folder (untracking them) then commit the change

Answer (score 5):

If the file has already been added to the index, it will still stay in there, even though you add it to the `.gitignore` file.

Try removing the file from the git index:

```
git rm --cached war/com.example.MyProject/com.example.MyProject.nocache.js
```

The `--cached` option makes sure that the file stays in your folder and just gets removed from the index

Comment: +1 for the supplemental explanation: "The --cached option makes sure that the file stays in your folder and just gets removed from the index".